# Buscar un registro que esté asociado a todos los registros de otra tabla

Tags: mysql, sql

Soy nuevo en SQL y estoy teniendo un problema para realizar una consulta.

Tengo una tabla "Alumnos" (id, nombre), una tabla "Materias" (id, nombre) e "Inscripciones" (id_alumno, id_materia) une las tablas Alumno y Materias.

En la tabla materias tengo 5 registros, en la tabla alumnos tengo 10 registros, y en inscripciones tengo 20 registros, entonces:

1. Como puedo traer solamente los alumnos que estén inscriptos a todas las materias?
2. Como puedo traer solamente los alumnos que estén inscriptos a más de 3 materias?

Comment: primero tienes que usar los joins, son varios pero el que necesitas se llama inner join, despues tendras que usar el WHERE para escribir las condiciones que necesitas que se cumplan, lo demas te lo dejo a ti.

Comment: Alex es importante q edites tu pregunta y pongas las consultas q has intentado para recibir ayuda

Answer (score -1, accepted):

espero esto te ayude saludos.

```
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE #alumnos(
    id int,
    nombre varchar(50)
    )

    CREATE TABLE #materias(
    id int,
    nombre varchar(50)
    )

    CREATE TABLE #inscripciones(
    id_alumno int,
    id_materia int
    )

    INSERT INTO #alumnos values(1,'Alumno 1');
    INSERT INTO #alumnos values(2,'Alumno 2');
    INSERT INTO #alumnos values(3,'Alumno 3');
    INSERT INTO #alumnos values(4,'Alumno 4');
    INSERT INTO #alumnos values(5,'Alumno 5');
    INSERT INTO #alumnos values(6,'Alumno 6');
    INSERT INTO #alumnos values(7,'Alumno 7');
    INSERT INTO #alumnos values(8,'Alumno 8');
    INSERT INTO #alumnos values(9,'Alumno 9');
    INSERT INTO #alumnos values(10,'Alumno 10');

    INSERT INTO #materias values(1,'Materia 1');
    INSERT INTO #materias values(2,'Materia 2');
    INSERT INTO #materias values(3,'Materia 3');
    INSERT INTO #materias values(4,'Materia 4');
    INSERT INTO #materias values(5,'Materia 5');

    INSERT INTO #inscripciones values(1,1);
    INSERT INTO #inscripciones values(1,2);
    INSERT INTO #inscripciones values(1,3);
    INSERT INTO #inscripciones values(1,4);
    INSERT INTO #inscripciones values(1,5);
    INSERT INTO #inscripciones values(2,1);
    INSERT INTO #inscripciones values(2,2);
    INSERT INTO #inscripciones values(2,3);
    INSERT INTO #inscripciones values(2,4);
    INSERT INTO #inscripciones values(2,5);
    INSERT INTO #inscripciones values(3,1);
    INSERT INTO #inscripciones values(3,2);
    INSERT INTO #inscripciones values(4,2);
    INSERT INTO #inscripciones values(4,3);
    INSERT INTO #inscripciones values(4,4);
    INSERT INTO #inscripciones values(4,5);
    INSERT INTO #inscripciones values(5,1);
    INSERT INTO #inscripciones values(6,1);
    INSERT INTO #inscripciones values(7,1);
    INSERT INTO #inscripciones values(8,1);


    /*Como puedo traer solamente los alumnos que estén inscriptos a todas las materias?*/
    declare @total_materias int 
    SET @total_materias = (Select Count(*) FROM #materias)

    Select a.id,a.nombre from #alumnos a
    INNER JOIN #inscripciones i
        on a.id = i.id_alumno
    group by a.id,a.nombre
    HAVING Count(i.id_materia) = @total_materias

    /*Como puedo traer solamente los alumnos que estén inscriptos a más de 3 materias?*/
    Select a.id,a.nombre from #alumnos a
    INNER JOIN #inscripciones i
        on a.id = i.id_alumno
    group by a.id,a.nombre
    HAVING Count(i.id_materia) > 3

    DROP TABLE #alumnos;
    DROP TABLE #materias;
    DROP TABLE #inscripciones;

END
```

Comment: Evita responder a preguntas donde el usuario no ha puesto lo que ha intentado, son las reglas del sitio, para ayudar a alguien este debe mostrar su esfuerzo

Comment: Ok vale, gracias.

Comment: Hola @Japv gracias ya leí el recorrido Gracias, de ahora en adelante tendré mas cuidado.

Comment: También debes tener cuidado porque respondiste una pregunta de MySQL con código de SQL Server. Por lo tanto, la solución puede no funcionar. Otro detalle es que no sabemos si la combinación alumno, materia es única en la tabla inscripciones, lo que puede dar falsos positivos o negativos.

Comment: Muchas gracias @FrankLopez
Lo traduje a MySQL y me sirvió.